# Mouse not clicking properly

Tags: 10.10, mouse, docky, window

Okay guys, here's a tricky one. I'm running 10.10 on my pc but i've had this issue for some time now.I'm having strange issues with the mouse. What happens is when I get into Ubuntu, I can click anything, but as soon as I click something to open a window, run a program, I can no longer click anything EXCEPT the last thing I clicked. When I right click the last thing I clicked, it allows me to click everything normally, but only until I open something new.
So for example I'll click the email icon on docky to open up my email client, which opens but is unresponsive until I right click docky. Then if I open an attatchment, I must also right click the MENU bar on my email client. Sometimes it also works if I simply right click on the newly opened window.
I have tried this mith mutiple mice and still the same issue.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` events for each of your mouse buttons in [`xev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xev).

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a clearlooks-theme? This may cause your mouse problems. Choose another theme.

Does your mouse problem persist with metacity? Try:

```
metacity --replace
```

See also: [mouse hover problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34123/mouse-hover-over-submenu-item-does-not-expand-menu-until-i-leave-and-re-enter-ite/34698#34698)

Comment: I'm having the same issue under Ambiance and Radiance, so at least for me it's not isolated to the Clearlooks theme. Removing the unity plugin hasn't helped, either.