# Mouse hover over submenu item does not expand menu until I leave and re-enter item

Tags: gnome, compiz, mouse, menu

In gnome, whenever I click on a contextual menu item (eg. right click on a window in the task bar) and then hover over a sub-item (eg. Move to another workspace) that is expandable, the submenu is not shown.

In order to show the submenu, I have to click about 4 times with my left mouse button OR leave the item again and re-hover the item with my mouse.

Why does the submenu item not expand automatically on the initial mouse-over (hover)?

Update: this is a pretty fresh install without any special interface software, just the default gnome installation. Ubuntu 10.10 with latest updates.

Also, this problem has been here since I installed Ubuntu a couple of months ago (the reason it is still a fresh install is because I rarely use Ubuntu, because of bugs like these).

Update:
My visual effects were on "normal". I then set them to "none", and now this issue has been resolved.

Comment: I have a similar problem with right click menus and Notification Area menus. What graphics hardware and driver are you using? Are you using `compiz` (aka normal or extra "visual effects")? I've always had a suspicion the `nvidia` driver has something to do with it.

Comment: I've got a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 video card, thus no nvidia.

Comment: It appears that the clearlook theme is the main suspect here.

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This could depend on your chosen theme. I've read a while ago, that someone had the same problems with the clearlooks-engine. He had chosen another theme and the problems were gone.
2. You can try to disable "Mouse Position Polling" in compiz.

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then goto System/Preferences an chose "Advanced Desktop Effects Settings" (i'm not sure if it is still called this way, because i use ubuntu in german) and disable Mouse Position Polling:

[image]

Comment: changing the theme to ambiance from clearlooks fixed it! It looks like there is a bug with the clearlooks theme.